# How to append multiple images in SVG using javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to append two images in different places in my svg. After this code i am able to see only one image. i couldnt get the second image. let me know what i am missing.

```
var imgs1 = svg.selectAll("image").data([0]);
imgs1.enter()
.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "assets/images/Down_Green.jpg")
.attr("x", 3)
.attr("y", 256)
.attr("width", "10")
.attr("height", "10");

var imgs2 = svg.selectAll("image").data([0]);
imgs2.enter()
.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "assets/images/Down_Green.jpg")
.attr("x", 210)
.attr("y", 256)
.attr("width", "10")
.attr("height", "10");
```

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer..

I did the following way and it worked..

```
var imgs1 = svg.append("g")
imgs1.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "assets/images/Down_Green.jpg")
.attr("x", 3)
.attr("y", 256)
.attr("width", "10")
.attr("height", "10");

var imgs2 = svg.append("g")
imgs2.append("svg:image")
.attr("xlink:href", "assets/images/Down_Green.jpg")
.attr("x", 210)
.attr("y", 256)
.attr("width", "10")
.attr("height", "10");
```

and now i am able to see two images.. :) :)